# Are there any code examples available for AWS Freertos for implementing a DHCP Server and HTTPS server?

Tags: aws-iot, freertos, mplab, pic32

I am wondering if anyone know if there is any sample code for implementing DHCP server and https server for AWS Freertos or if not then maybe for Freertos? The purpose for this is purely for WiFi provisioning so a lean implementation would be what I'm after.

My device is a PIC32MZ-W so it has built in Wifi (using Bluetooth for provisioning is not possible as it is not supported by this device, at least not without additional hardware).

I've searched both AWS Freertos and Freertos, but as far as I can see there are some comments on it but no guidance or examples seems to be readily available.

Thanks,
Marcus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty examples in the freeRTOS default folder that you can download from the offical website ( https://www.freertos.org/a00104.html ).

One of the examples would be here: \FreeRTOS-10.0.1\FreeRTOS\Demo\lwIP_Demo_Rowley_ARM7\lwip-1.1.0\src\core\dhcp.c

Comment: thanks looks like there will be quite some effort in getting this up and running, will review the code and see how to proceed. Was hopping this would be more plug and play and not need to get into details of DHCP and webserver for provisioning.